# understanding my site's DNS records

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

firstly apologies for using the word 'pointage' this is the word my french domain registrar uses so I may have used to wrong term.

OK I would like to better understand what is going on on my 'pointage' record on my domain registrars site.

for my (currently empty) web site it reports the following details...

```
Type  : Host              : Destination
A     : www.mydomain.org  : 62.210.176.146
A     : mail.mydomain.org : 84.246.225.176
Mx    :     .mydomain.org : mail.mydomain.org
```

I think I understand the MX record, that simply relays anything onto the mail.mydomain.org location.
However why are the destination for the www and mail domains different.
Even more confusing (for me) is the fact that if I ping either of www.mydomain.org or mail.mydomain.org the ping returns a different IP address. This IP address is consistent with that of my server (ie 92.39.247.92).

So what exactly is going on ?

I'm sure I could find the information on the web,I've read a few thing on the debianhelp site regarding DNS records, and it seems to suggest that the record should be a reverse lookup, but certains isn't the reverse of my servers IP ?
 but I don't what I should be looking for,  so links to docs and search terms for google will be happily accepteed (even though they go against the grain of SO answers to question).

thanks in advance.

David.

ps. I should add that everything seems to work just fine, and I've just descovered this part of the management page of my registrar.

Edit: Addition of DNS records and ping results.

The DNS record for the site. From what I've read there should only realy be a single 'A' record, so has something gone wrong ? should I change it (remove the extras and then just point www.facilitee.org -> .facilitee.org and mail.facilitee.org -> .facilitee.org

here is the DNS record
    A   www.facilitee.org   ⇢   92.39.247.92 
    A   .facilitee.org  ⇢   92.39.247.92
    A   mail.facilitee.org  ⇢   92.39.247.92
    A   webmail.facilitee.org   ⇢ 92.39.247.92
    MX  .facilitee.org  ⇢   mail.facilitee.org

ping results...

```
~$ ping www.facilitee.org
PING www.facilitee.org (92.39.247.92) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from vps4576-cloud.dns26.com (92.39.247.92):
~$ ping mail.facilitee.org
PING mail.facilitee.org (92.39.247.92) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from vps4576-cloud.dns26.com (92.39.247.92):
```

So the DNS and the ping correspond, but the 'pointage' doesn't.

~ how can I get a report of the pointage records other than from my registrar ?

Comment: think you need to ask your hosting company about this, looks like  your DNS does not reflect reality.. but also if you just changed it, and if you TTL is high, it could take many hours before it is updated everywhere

Comment: @Sverre My minimal understanding is very minimal. I'm not even sure where to look in the first instance.

Answer (score 4):

Your website works from a webserver and mails are handled by mail server. It is totally fine to have a different IP address for both mail server and webserver. As per the details you have provided this is the case.

Reverse DNS is a totally different aspect.

**Updated reply.**

For a domain to work, we need to set Nameservers (NS) records. Also it needs an A record. I am not sure if the requirement is for NS records. I can see that the nameservers that are set for the domain is NS1.DNS26.NET and NS2.DNS26.NET. A DNS entry can have multiple A records, there is no issues.

```
A www.facilitee.org ⇢ 92.39.247.92 
A .facilitee.org ⇢ 92.39.247.92
A mail.facilitee.org ⇢ 92.39.247.92 
A webmail.facilitee.org ⇢ 92.39.247.92 
MX .facilitee.org ⇢ mail.facilitee.org
```

First 4 A records, ensure that www, the domain name, mail and webmail subdomains work fine. The 5th entry is for MX or mail exchange.

Your website is working from the IP address *92.39.247.92* and when you ping it shows the reverse dns which is *vps4576-cloud.dns26.com*

The ping result is also perfect. What it says is that the domain is working from an IP address of 92.39.247.92 which has reverse DNS set to vps4576-cloud.dns26.com.

Comment: but both the web server and mail server are on my vps that has an ip of 92.39.247.92 which is consistent with the ip from a ping to either of them

Comment: @DaveM, could you please show a snippet of the ping results, so that I shall update with more details. If you provide the domain name itself, then a lot more info could be passed on. But as your doubt is with regard to ping to mail. and www. please let us know the ping results.

Comment: added the info to the question as requested.

Comment: @DaveM, I have updated the answer, please see if that makes sense.

Comment: your answer is great but misses the main part of my question: where does the 84.246.225.176 IP come from, and why does mail.facilitee.org point to it rather than the IP of my server (92.39.247.92), and is it going to cause me grief with my mail server?

Comment: I can't see the ip 84.246.225.176 anywhere. ping to www.facilitee.org, facilitee.org and mail.facilitee.org all return the ip 92.39.247.92. Where are you seeing a different ip?

Comment: that is exactly the point. This info is on the site of the company that I get my VPS from. It has a page on the web admin that say 'reinitialisation' and these details are in the defaults. Just couldn't work out where they came from. Reading the page again, I guess it doesn't realy matter at the correct records give the responses I would expect.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your domain is parked. Both of those IP addresses are registered to [Netissime](http://www.netissime.com/), which seems to be your registrar.

When you actually set up your own web and email services, you can change those records to point to your own servers.

Comment: Indeed Netissime is my registrar. but I'm still unsure why a ping to either will report a differenct ip address ~ ie that of my server? Is is something to do with the ip of the 'host' machine (as I am on a vps ? Web services work fine (or the do when I put the pages live, I'm still in testing so they go up and down regularly!) email is a slightly different matter... still pulling my hair out with it, but learning.

Comment: You didn't tell us what your domain is, so it's impossible to look this up.

Comment: the domain is facilitee.org, I've added other info into my question